# How to make background image clip on left side instead of right when resizing

Tags: css, background-image

Whenever I resize the window, my background image gets clipped on the right side, while the left size of image remains fixed. Is there any way to reverse that behavior, and make the background-image clip on the left side?

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://www.miis.edu/system/files/media/sailboats_0.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

I have a Plunkr demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOlpUcTkGdU8aLYClzFY?p=preview).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may or may not fit your needs but you could give a [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) of `right 0` to the element in order to position the background image at the right/top of the box.

**[Example Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RRlMKGVCnBYAvcIv17bT?p=preview)**

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://www.miis.edu/system/files/media/sailboats_0.jpg);
  background-position: right 0;
}
```

This won't work with SVG, however. In the case of applying this CSS to an SVG image, you'd need to use it on an SVG element in your markup.

Comment: Hashem, sorry, didn't specify correct styles. Please see update. Your approach doesn't work with updated setup. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Maximus As per your update where the element is positioned absolutely, try giving it a `right: 0;` - **[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBP4smDe0bjZjV48z0ja?p=preview)** So that it would position at the right side of its containing block / the initial containing block in the demo.

Comment: Year, that works. I just needed to give it negative right margin instead of 0 since my background goes beyond website content to the right. Thanks, best!